# Swift 3 API renaming in subclasses

Tags: ios, swift, methods, uicollectionview, subclass

I've encountered some unexpected behaviour in my code where `UICollectionViewDelegate` callbacks are only received if I use the pre-Swift 3 method signatures.

To demonstrate this issue, I have created two view controller subclasses:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    }

//  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
//      print(#function)
//  }
}

class SubViewController: ViewController {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(#function)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(#function)
    }
}
```

The callback of interest is the `collectionView(_:willDisplay:forItemAt:)` method.

The first thing to note is that if I add the old variant of that method (`collectionView(_:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:)`) to `ViewController`, the compiler helpfully warns me that the method has been renamed:

```
'collectionView(_:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:)' has been renamed to 'collectionView(_:willDisplay:forItemAt:)'
```

However adding the same method to `SubViewController` produces no warning – it seems to treat it like it would any other previously-undefined method.

If I run the app with an instance of `ViewController` (uncomment the `collectionView(_:willDisplay:at:)` method there, and comment it out in `SubViewController`), the correct delegate method (with the new method name) is called. If I instead use the class `SubViewController`, the incorrect delegate method (with the old method name) is called.

Is this the correct behaviour? If so, why? It makes it somewhat difficult to reason about which method signatures I should use, especially when there seems to be no compile-time checking of the method that is actually called in `SubViewController`.

Comment: When I copy your example, I get an error on the SubViewController methods. `collectionView(_:willDisplay:forItemAt:)` has error `Overriding declaration requires an 'override' keyword`. `collectionView(_:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:)` has error `Method 'collectionView(_:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:)' with Objective-C selector 'collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:' conflicts with method 'collectionView(_:willDisplay:forItemAt:)' with the same Objective-C selector`. Xcode 8.0.

Comment: @MikeTaverne Sorry yes, you need to comment out the method in the class not currently being tested. I've made that clearer in an edit to the question.

Comment: Adding `@objc (collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:)` above the method with new name in the subclass (and remove the method with old name) makes the method with new name get called. Just wanted to add a bit info that I found.

Comment: So apparently Swift 3 method name translating rule does not apply **at runtime**. This should be a bug.

Comment: @pedrouan - It's not possible to post a screenshot as a comment which is why I posted it as an answer.

Comment: I get the same results, and @ThanhPham's solution works. Not sure if this was by design, but it is confusing to say the least.

Comment: I reported this as a bug here https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2885. It would be great if any of you could help in wording the bug description and/or providing more information.

Comment: Thanks for filling that bug report. There is another issue, [SR-2817](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2817), concerning Swift method renaming in protocol & extensions that might actually be related.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in one of the comments the solution to this problem is to add `@objc` in front of the function like this.

```
@objc (collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:)
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // code goes here
}
```